# run this method when my state change status

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a this code, and I would like to run this, when my state `desktopOpen: true` toggle boolean state.

```
  handleResize() {
    const evt = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents');
    evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
```

Comment: How do you toggle the state? Are you using a state manager (e.g., Redux) that allows spying on state changes? Where does this function live? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback immediately wherever you're setting your state and can update the event in the callback.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  desktopOpen: !prevState.desktopOpen
}), () => {
  if (this.state.desktopOpen) {
    const evt = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents');
    evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
});
```